# How do I use texStorage2D?

Tags: webgl2

Does anyone have a working, end-to-end example of this API in WebGL 2 or could point me to one? I did a search already and couldn't find anything but the API documentation.

I'd like to know how the calls would differ from what I currently do? Do I still need the following calls? Are there equivalents for them for Storage 2D?

- createTexture
- bindTexture
- texSubStorage2D? (how do i upload data?)
- activeTexture
- framebufferTexture2D
- readPixels

Comment: I just did a call like the following `gl.texStorage2D( gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.R32F, width, height)` and `gl.getError()` returns `INVALID_VALUE` each time regardless of the size of the texture. A valid texture object is created and bound each time

Comment: Actually the problem was the 0 for layers. It has to be greater than or equal to 1. Setting it to 1 solved my problem